# Multiple post queries -category,posts per page,orderby

Tags: query-posts

I originally had this query on a posts category page:

```
        <?php $page_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&cat=145'); ?>
```

Which worked, but it only displayed the first 4 posts. So I wanted to display all the posts from the category, as well as change the posts per page limit, as well as set the orderby for good measure. However, this query returns EVERY post on my site, regardless of category:

```
        <?php $page_query = new WP_Query('post_type=post&cat=145'. '&posts_per_page=-1&cat' . '&orderby=date&order=asc'); ?>
```

Seems like it should work in theory. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the `cat` parameter twice-- the second time is empty.

```
$page_query = new WP_Query(
    'post_type=post&cat=145'. 
    '&posts_per_page=-1&cat' . // <-- here
    '&orderby=date&order=asc'
);
```

Maybe it is just me, but I find those query-string-like parameters hard to read and hard to keep straight. I'd advise you to create a proper array.

```
$page_query = new WP_Query(
    array (
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'cat' => 145, 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'order' => 'asc'
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks! Should it be `'cat' => 145`?

Comment: Yes. Corrected it.